# MPAndroidChart x axis

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I try to display some charts in my android app. I use MPAndroidChart library. But somehow my chart is always compress on the x-axis. The value seems to have all the x value 0.
In the data set this is not the case. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
val chart = binding.statsGraph
chart.description.isEnabled = false
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
chart.setDrawBarShadow(false)
chart.isHighlightFullBarEnabled = false
chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
chart.setDrawBarShadow(false)
chart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false)
// draw bars behind lines
chart.setDrawOrder(
    arrayOf(
        CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR,
        CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BUBBLE,
        CombinedChart.DrawOrder.CANDLE,
        CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE,
        CombinedChart.DrawOrder.SCATTER
    )
)

val legend = chart.getLegend()
legend.isWordWrapEnabled = true
legend.verticalAlignment = Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM
legend.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER
legend.orientation = Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL
legend.setDrawInside(false)

val rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight()
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0f // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

val leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft()
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0f // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

val xAxis = chart.getXAxis()
xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED
xAxis.axisMinimum = 0f
xAxis.granularity = 1f
class MyValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return value.toInt().toString()
    }
}
xAxis.valueFormatter = MyValueFormatter()

val data = CombinedData()
data.setData(test())

xAxis.axisMaximum = data.xMax + 0.25f
chart.setData(data)
chart.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your layout and its parent layout has a "match_parent" width.